# Is it safe to use _msize with new[]?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc

Is it safe to use Microsoft specific _msize() function with new []?

Example:

```
  int* i = new int[100];      
  size_t s = _msize(i);    
  cout << "Size of the array in bytes: " << s << endl;
  delete [] i;
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2s077bc.aspx) does describe just the usage with malloc & Co.

I've tested the code with Visual Studio 2010, and it looks to work! But i would like to know if there are some expected issues or any special cases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There could be a problem if someone overrides `operator new` for your type.

It is just as easy to write

```
const size_t s = 100;
int* i = new int[s];
```

or, if you really write C++

```
std::vector<int>   i(100);
```

Answer (score 3):

Will works correct if and only if `operator new[]` is realized by `malloc & Co.`

Answer (score 3):

> The _msize function returns the size, in bytes, of the memory block
>   allocated by a call to calloc, malloc, or realloc.

So if `operator new` is implemented by `malloc()`, it will work. Otherwise, or if `operator new` gets overridden, you will have trouble.